# pass char to function

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, return-type, function-definition

i need to write a function that randomize length of string, allocate dynamic memory for it and than randomize small letters inside it.
the main program should print 15 words from the function.
the function by itself works for me, i just can't pass it from the main program.
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 15

char randWord() {
    int len;
    srand(time(NULL));
    len = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    char * word = malloc(len);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        word[i] = ((rand() % 26) + 97);     
    }

    return word;
}

int main() {
    char* s;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        randWord(s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
        free(s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *randWord() `

Comment: Return the pointer, but also remember you're responsible for releasing that memory.

Comment: When `main()` calls `randWord()` it passes an argument, but `randWord()` isn't declared to take any arguments.

Comment: @sj95126 Technically it's declared to take any arguments, as in C unless you declare it as `(void)` it just ignores them.

Comment: @tadman: That wasn't really my point - `s` is passed to `randWord()` but it's not able to use it.

Comment: Also `s = randWord();`

Comment: i changed it to s = randWord(); 
now it works thank you everybody

Comment: Your randWord function doesn't null-terminate the populated string, and that string is one byte too short.

Comment: Not a good idea to re-seed the random number generator inside a tight loop. Call `srand()` once in main(), then just use `rand()`...

Comment: @sj95126 What I'm trying to say is that `f()` takes *any* arguments and ignores them while `f(void)` fails if you pass arguments, it won't accept them. This is a subtle quirk of how C works, and can trip up people a lot, as evidenced here. The function is declared to take arguments, just not how people expect them to work.

Comment: @tadman: That still wasn't my point. Passing `s` to `randWord()` when it can't use it doesn't accomplish anything. I'm not talking in any way whatsoever about the legality of passing unexpected arguments. Anyway, there's no point in discussing it further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your function to accept parameters, and potentially return a char pointer.

```
char* randWord(char* s)
```

I think you might have a misunderstanding of functions in general. They can optionally take in parameters, and optionally return something.

A really simple example would be something like this:

```
int addOne(int x) { 
  return x + 1;
}
```

It may help to think of programming functions in terms of math functions. the above is equivalent to `f(x)=x+1`. So `f(1)` "returns" `2`, `f(2)` is `3` and so on.

Comment: `randWord` is meant to dynamically allocate a string of a random length and return a pointer to it. `char *randWord()` is a more appropriate signature. Passing `s` into it is just another bug in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The function is declared without parameters

```
char randWord() {
```

but you are passing a pointer of the type `char *`.

```
randWord(s)
```

The function returns a pointer of the type `char *` but its return type is `char`.

```
char randWord() {
    int len;
    srand(time(NULL));
    len = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    char * word = malloc(len);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        word[i] = ((rand() % 26) + 97);     
    }
    return word;
}
```

Also the function does not build a string because the dynamically allocated character array does not contain the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

And it is a bad style of programming to use magic numbers like 97.

Redefine the function at least like

```
char * randWord( void ) {
    size_t len = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    char * word = malloc(len);
    
    if ( word != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for (; i < len - 1; i++) {
            word[i] = ((rand() % 26) + 'a');     
        }
        word[i] = '\0';     
    }

    return word;
}
```

and in main write

```
s = randWord();
if ( s != NULL ) puts( s );
free( s );
```

This statement

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

should be moved from the function to main before its for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code annotated and altered to function correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 15

char *randWord() { // Return ptr to word buffer (the string)
    int len = rand() % 10 + 1; // knowing operator precedence avoids overuse of ( )

    char *word = malloc( len + 1 ); // allow room for '\0'
    if( word == NULL )
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // do not presume success

    // Here "len" is the # of chars to generate (at least one)
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        word[i] = rand() % 26 + 'a'; // use ASCII value, not magic number
    }
    word[i] = '\0'; // TERMINATE the string

    return word;
}

int main() { // be consistent with braces
    srand( time( NULL ) ); // Seed the random number generator only once

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) { // Be consistent
        char *s = randWord(); // declare variables proximate to use. Strive for clarity
        puts( s ); // Simpler function than printf
        free( s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is a subtlety of your code that the returned string will always be at least one character long.